# We are getting CORS issue in Azure WebAPP still i have allowed all origin as "*"

Tags: cors, azure-web-app-service

I am getting CORS issue in PROD environment when i am try to login into the site.when i set origin policy as "*" . still it is giving the same CORS issue.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/api/users/userlogin' from origin 'https://XYZ.azurewebsites.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I also have specified the CORS policy in code as well but Azure Web App CORS policy always have precedence over Code CORS policy.

can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Removed all code-handling of CORS and simply put the headers in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/api/users/userlogin" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type, x-my-custom-header" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

**Note**: Don't try to use App Service CORS and Web API  CORS code together. When used together, App Service CORS takes precedence and Web API  CORS code has no effect. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#app-service-cors-versus-web-api-cors).

Comment: Thanks fro suggestion. please also let me know or share the link to add CORS policy in appsetting file in ASP.NET core Web API.?

Comment: Here is an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1225152/Asp-net-web-API-CORS-problem) you could refer to.

Comment: Hi Joey, Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: I have implemented changes as per your suggestion still getting the same issue.it might be due to the azure  APP service.

Comment: @manojkumar I am also facing excatly same issue.. Did u happen to find the solution??

Comment: any solution for the apps hosted on the Linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

- Restart the Azure Web App.

I found that Azure Web App CORS service is a little slow to implement changed config - I would still get CORS failure using the updated valid config (`*` as the only entry) *immediately* after saving the change.

It was only after restarting the Azure Web App + few minutes + another restart did my requests start working. Same exact config through the whole process.