# Issues after deploying azure QnA bot to Azure environment

Tags: python, node.js, azure, flask

I have bot code (node.js) which is deployed into azure by compressing and dropping into https://test.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI, we have python files and flask in our local machine and before i was testing with emulator it worked fine, now after deployed into azure and testing it in Web Chat the local host flask api is not working.
kindly help me how can i communicate flask api from azure bot

Error msges:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net/botservice/api/Telemetry' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net/botservice/api/ClientTrace' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

In CORS:
[In App Service i have given * and removed all other origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNwK.png)

Errors:
[These are the errors i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0pBL.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure azure portal > your resource group > your app service > Settings > CORS looks like this:

[image]

Please follow below doc for deployment of Bot:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Also check this for additional reference:

[We are getting CORS issue in Azure WebAPP still i have allowed all origin as "*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701444/we-are-getting-cors-issue-in-azure-webapp-still-i-have-allowed-all-origin-as)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mohit Verma, i will try this.

Comment: still i am facing the issue: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net/botservice/api/Telemetry' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
18Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<URL>' from origin '<URL>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.